Update Target Audience from Node.js - Sharepoint Server 2019
I am trying to write a function that can apply target audience from within a node js application. I am working with SharePoint Server 2019.
This Audience column is a special type and I have to query the items out of the list using a caml query and the GetItems endpoint:
 const camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Audience' /></IsNull></Where></Query></View>";

    const spResponse = await client.fetch(`${contextURL}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${docLibTitle}')/GetItems`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': digestValue
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'query': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
                'ViewXml': camlQuery
            }
        })
    });

How do I actually update that field using the REST Api?
I have tried this:
const payload = {
            '__metadata': { 'type': item.__metadata.type },
            'Audience': `;;;;${targetAudienceGroups.join(' ').trim()}`
        };

        const response = await client.fetch(`${contextURL}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${docLibTitle}')/items(${item.Id})`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
                'IF-MATCH': '*',
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'X-RequestDigest': digestValue
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        });

But that doesn't work and returns a 400 error and says 'Audience' is not a column of that list. I have a C# script that can already do this, but I was hoping I could also update this field from node and not have to build a C# micro service.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks.
